# How to identify Bulk Data Load Jobs in the log files

Tags: data-loader, debugging

I am trying to dig into our logs and see what is really happening behind the scenes when we bulk data load data into SFDC, but I can't seem to id the operation name in the logs connected with the data load process. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm pulling my hair out.  I just want to see an error or at least the request as it was received by Salesforce.  I got it all working fine in Postman, and I can't see any differences in request from code.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:
1) Enable debug logs for the user who submitted the batch load job (Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs) OR
2) Log on as the user submitting the batch load job and open the Developer Console. In the Logs tab the jobs should start appearing as they progress.

Comment: I've been trying number 2, the problem I have is that I don't know which log is the bulk-api log and when I open them up to try and detect, nothing is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go under monitoring in SFDC set up

Monitoring>Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs

Here you should see your record .

Comment: That works for seeing if the job worked and what the result was, I want to see the full log. What triggers it caused, the size of the heap, etc.

Comment: open a system log for the user dataloading .i guess that should work